# How to compute different aggregations on the same dataframe in parallel on PySpark?

Tags: python, performance, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to compute by hand some custom summary statistics of a large dataframe on PySpark. For the sake of simplicity, let me use a simpler dummy dataset, as the following:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import DataType, NumericType, DateType, TimestampType
import pyspark.sql.types as t
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from datetime import datetime

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .appName("pyspark")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
)
dd = [
    ("Alice", 18.0, datetime(2022, 1, 1)),
    ("Bob", None, datetime(2022, 2, 1)),
    ("Mark", 33.0, None),
    (None, 80.0, datetime(2022, 4, 1)),
]
schema = t.StructType(
    [
        t.StructField("T", t.StringType()),
        t.StructField("C", t.DoubleType()),
        t.StructField("D", t.DateType()),
    ]
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(dd, schema)
```

Ok, the thing is, I want to compute some aggregations: `missing counts`, `stddev`, `max` and `min` from all the columns, and of course **I'd want to do it in parallel**. Well, I can take two approaches for this:

### Approach 1: One select query

This way, I let the Spark engine make the parallel computing by making **one big select query**. Let's see:

```py
def df_dtypes(df: DataFrame) -> List[Tuple[str, DataType]]:
    """
    Like df.dtypes attribute of Spark DataFrame, but returning DataType objects instead
    of strings.
    """
    return [(str(f.name), f.dataType) for f in df.schema.fields]

def get_missing(df: DataFrame) -> Tuple:
    suffix = "__missing"
    result = (
        *(
            (
                f.count(
                    f.when(
                        (f.isnan(c) | f.isnull(c)),
                        c,
                    )
                )
                / f.count("*")
                * 100
                if isinstance(t, NumericType)  # isnan only works for numeric types
                else f.count(
                    f.when(
                        f.isnull(c),
                        c,
                    )
                )
                / f.count("*")
                * 100
            )
            .cast("double")
            .alias(c + suffix)
            for c, t in df_dtypes(df)
        ),
    )

    return result

def get_min(df: DataFrame) -> Tuple:
    suffix = "__min"
    result = (
        *(
            (f.min(c) if isinstance(t, (NumericType, DateType, TimestampType)) else f.lit(None))
            .cast(t)
            .alias(c + suffix)
            for c, t in df_dtypes(df)
        ),
    )
    return result

def get_max(df: DataFrame) -> Tuple:
    suffix = "__max"
    result = (
        *(
            (f.max(c) if isinstance(t, (NumericType, DateType, TimestampType)) else f.lit(None))
            .cast(t)
            .alias(c + suffix)
            for c, t in df_dtypes(df)
        ),
    )
    return result

def get_std(df: DataFrame) -> Tuple:
    suffix = "__std"
    result = (
        *(
            (f.stddev(c) if isinstance(t, NumericType) else f.lit(None)).cast(t).alias(c + suffix)
            for c, t in df_dtypes(df)
        ),
    )
    return result

# build the big query
query = get_min(df) + get_max(df) + get_missing(df) + get_std(df)

# run the job
df.select(*query).show()
```

As far as I know, this job will run in parallel because the internals of Spark works. Is this approach efficient? The problem with this might be the huge number of columns with suffixes that it creates, could it be a bottle neck?

### Approach 2: Using threads

In this approach, I can make use of Python threads to try to perform each calculation concurrently.

```py
from pyspark import InheritableThread
from queue import Queue

def get_min(df: DataFrame, q: Queue) -> None:
    result = df.select(
        f.lit("min").alias("summary"),
        *(
            (f.min(c) if isinstance(t, (NumericType, DateType, TimestampType)) else f.lit(None))
            .cast(t)
            .alias(c)
            for c, t in df_dtypes(df)
        ),
    ).collect()
    q.put(result)


def get_max(df: DataFrame, q: Queue) -> None:
    result = df.select(
        f.lit("max").alias("summary"),
        *(
            (f.max(c) if isinstance(t, (NumericType, DateType, TimestampType)) else f.lit(None))
            .cast(t)
            .alias(c)
            for c, t in df_dtypes(df)
        ),
    ).collect()
    q.put(result)


def get_std(df: DataFrame, q: Queue) -> None:
    result = df.select(
        f.lit("std").alias("summary"),
        *(
            (f.stddev(c) if isinstance(t, NumericType) else f.lit(None)).cast(t).alias(c)
            for c, t in df_dtypes(df)
        ),
    ).collect()
    q.put(result)

def get_missing(df: DataFrame, q: Queue) -> None:
    result = df.select(
        f.lit("missing").alias("summary"),
        *(
            (
                f.count(
                    f.when(
                        (f.isnan(c) | f.isnull(c)),
                        c,
                    )
                )
                / f.count("*")
                * 100
                if isinstance(t, NumericType)  # isnan only works for numeric types
                else f.count(
                    f.when(
                        f.isnull(c),
                        c,
                    )
                )
                / f.count("*")
                * 100
            )
            .cast("double")
            .alias(c)
            for c, t in df_dtypes(df)
        ),
    ).collect()
    q.put(result)

# caching the dataframe to reuse it for all the jobs?
df.cache()
# I use a queue to retrieve the results from the threads
q = Queue()
threads = [
    InheritableThread(target=fun, args=(df, q)).start()
    for fun in (get_min, get_max, get_missing, get_std)
]
# and then some code to recover the results from the queue
```

This way has the advantage of not ending up with dozens of columns with suffixes, just the original columns. But I'm not sure how this way deals with the GIL, is that actually parallel?

Could you tell me which one do you prefer? Or some suggestions about different ways to compute them?

At the end I want to build a JSON with all of this aggregated statistics. The structure of JSON is not relevant, it would depend on the approach taken. For the first one, I'd get something like {"T__min": None, "T__max": None, "T__missing": 1, "T__std": None, "C__min": 18.0, "C__max": 80.0, ...} so this way I end up with tons of fields and the select query would be huge. For the second approach I would get one JSON per variable with those statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with the `InheritableThread` and `Queue`, but as far as I can see, you want to create threads based on statistics. Meaning, every thread calculating a different statistic. This doesn't look optimized by design. I mean, some statistics will likely be calculated quicker than others. And then your processing power in those threads will not be used.

As you know, Spark is a distributed computing system which performs all the parallelism for you. I very highly doubt you can outperform Spark's optimization using Python's tools. If we could do that, it would already be integrated into Spark.

The first approach is very nicely written: conditional statements based on data types, inclusion of isnan, type hints - well done. It would probably perform the best it's possible, it's *definitely written efficiently*. The biggest drawback is the nature that it will be run on the whole dataframe, but you can't really escape that. Regarding the number of columns, you shouldn't be worried. The whole select statement will be very long, but it's just one operation. The logical/physical plan should be efficient. In worst-case scenario, you could persist/cache the dataframe before this operation, as you may have problems if this dataframe is created using some complex code. But other than that you should be fine.

As an alternative, for some statistics you may consider using `summary`:

```py
df.summary().show()
# +-------+-----+------------------+
# |summary|    T|                 C|
# +-------+-----+------------------+
# |  count|    3|                 3|
# |   mean| null|43.666666666666664|
# | stddev| null| 32.34707611722168|
# |    min|Alice|              18.0|
# |    25%| null|              18.0|
# |    50%| null|              33.0|
# |    75%| null|              80.0|
# |    max| Mark|              80.0|
# +-------+-----+------------------+
```

This approach would only work for numeric and string columns. Date/Timestamp columns (e.g. "D") are automatically excluded. But I'm not sure if this would be more efficient. And definitely it would be less clear, as it would add additional logic to your code which now is quite straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! and why threading approach would not be well optimized, because the python GIL? So, there is not overhead in selecting a huge number of columns?

Comment: Regarding the select, the select statement is just 1 line in the physical plan (the line would be very long in your case). The Spark engine should be able to handle it. Spark has problems when you create very big query plans (many lines, repetitive lines, etc.). In your case, it's just one, so I see no problem. Regarding the attempt to control threading, I have touched on one aspect in the answer - threads would perform tasks which will have different complexity, so you would end up not using resources effectively.

Comment: Regarding Python's GIL, Spark is not run by Python, its JVM under the hood, so you may cause more problems, as threading then may be attempted to be controlled by both...  Also, I just trust the collective experience of Spark developers - I highly doubt Python's thread control tools may do any positive effect. But this is just my guess, as I have never worked with Python's threading control tools.